# Getting error in Laravel 5.7 edit route page not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.7

Laravel Version 5.7
PHP 7+

I created a resource controller -> CategoryController [having all the magic methods]

This is the routes/web.php

```html
Route::group(['as'=>'admin.','middleware'=>['auth','admin'],'prefix'=>'admin'], function(){
    Route::get('/dashboard','AdminController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');

    // product resource controller methods
    // check php artisan r:l
    Route::resource('product', 'ProductController');
    Route::resource('category', 'CategoryController');

    Route::resource('profile', 'ProfileController');
    Route::post('remove', 'CategoryController@remove')->name('category.remove');
});
```

[image]

---

Now as you can see, I have "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/category/1/edit" for one of my categories to edit with category id = 1, that is also stored in the database.

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Category;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::paginate(3);
        return view('admin.categories.index',compact('categories'));
    }
    
    public function edit(Category $category)
    {
        return "This is category edit page";
        // dd($category);
        //  $categories = Category::where('id','!=', $category->id)->get();
        // //  dd($categories);
        // return "This is category edit page";
        //  return view('admin.categories.create',['categories' => $categories, 'category'=>$category]);
    }
```

When I try to go to this edit category page, it shows 404 page not found error.

Although, when I made an individual route for edit method with a closure function to return some text, it worked perfectly.

```html
    Route::get('category/{category}/edit', function($category){
        return $category;
    })->name('category.edit');
```

Comment: basically the controller function should be like this :  public function edit($id) {} . isn't it ?

Comment: Your code is correct, According to me, may be something other issue

Answer (score 3):

You didn't excluded full error you get, but try to change:

```
public function edit(Category $category)
{
    return "This is category edit page";
}
```

into:

```
public function edit($category)
{
    return "This is category edit page";
}
```

and see if it helps. If it helps, it means that there is no record matching id you passed or this record is soft deleted (or some additional conditions are not met) - Laravel uses Route model binding to match valid record.

Comment: Although I solved the error, But you are correct, that was the error, model type hinting. I was passing id as the parameter, but the slug was defined in the getRouteKeyName method under CategoryController.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function edit(Request $category)
{
    return "This is category edit page";
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.